# Spring MVC project - take input of form and return results of Java method on same page

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This is my first MVC project, so I'm sorry that this question is so basic! But, I have a function that takes in a URL and returns information about it in the form of Strings. On my home.jsp page I want to have a form that allows the user to input the URL and have the information returned on the same page. How should I go about doing this? I have a HomeController that came with my project template--I don't know if I need a special controller?

So far, I have:

home.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" action="getTumblrData" commandName="tumblrInfo">
    <input name="url" type="text"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form:form>
<div id="returnedInfo">
<!-- return data should go here -->
</div>
```

tumblrInfo.java

```
public class tumblrInfo {
    private String blogname;
    public String getBlogName() {
        return blogname;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.blogname = name;
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
public String UrlReader(String url) {
   String blogName;
   ...
   return blogName;
}

@RequestMapping("/home")
public String getTumblrData(@ModelAttribute("tumblrInfo") tumblrInfo data, Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) {
 String blogName = UrlReader(data.getURL());
 return blogName???
 }
```

Obviously when I run the program and click submit nothing happens. Can someone point me in the right direction? I am comfortable with html/javascript/jquery, if those are needed. I'm a little overwhelmed with the MVC framework libraries right now.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `org.springframework.ui.Model` for model attributes here. So add the attributes to your model and return name of the JSP you want displayed. Also you need to add a POST argument to your `@RequestMapping` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getTumblrData(@ModelAttribute("tumblrInfo") tumblrInfo data, Model model, ...) {
   String blogName = UrlReader(data.getURL());
   model.addAttribute("blogName", blogName);
   return "my-jsp-page";
}
```

and in the JSP:

```
<div id="returnedInfo">
   ${blogName}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I implemented these changes and still nothing happens when I press submit :/ I added a System.out.print in my getTumblrData function and I don't see it printed in console when I'm debugging, so it looks like the function isn't even being called?

Comment: Any errors being displayed? Do you have `HomeController` annotated with the `@Controller` annotation?

Comment: No and yes. I'm not really sure how to debug this.